# Has anyone ever implemented joomla 3 content approval workflow

Tags: joomla3.0

I am currently using joomla 3. I have a scenario where by content has to go through approval before it is published. Has anyone ever implemented the same in joomla 3

Comment: Your question is not worded very well.  Snarky volunteers could post a valid yet unhelpful answer of "Yes" or "No".  If you are asking for extension recommendations, then this page will be closed as requesting a software recommendation.  If you are seeking support for a coding attempt that you have made, please include that in your post. If you haven't yet looked in the Joomla Extension Directory -- please do that.  After all that, I encourage you to post your Joomla-specific question on Joomla Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

For content Approval you simply need to make default publishing to unpublished when you create a menu item for Content creation at Frontend. The image below will help you.
[image]

So when a user submits it will be unpublished by default and either a super admin or anyone authorised to approve like administrator, manager, publisher can approve the same either through frontend or backend.